# How do I request from the deployed API on Vercel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel

This is how the file structure looks like

```
root
  client
  index.js
  package-lock.json
  package.json
  routes.js
```

When I send a request to my API the status is 200 but it says You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
My client is on the same path "/" and "/login", and my api is at "/api/"
And my client requests on ${url}/api with axios.

This is my vercel.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `vercel.json` configuration, it seems that your routes configuration is incorrect. It is routing all requests, including API requests, to the root path ("/"), which may be causing the issue you're facing.

Modify your `vercel.json` as follows

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "/api/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(?!api)(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```